# Kubuntu 16.04 (Plasma 5) connect to VPN

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, kde, vpn, kde5

I want to connect to our company VPN.

I found [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html) on official Ubuntu documentation but that is not valid for Kubuntu or KDE desktop environment.

Is there alternative way to do this on Kubuntu or via terminal?

Comment: What guide you followed that's not for Kubuntu? Have you tred openvpn?

Comment: @Anwar https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/ubuntu-help/net-vpn-connect.html

Comment: Is your company using PPTP or openVpn? The instructions should come from the company in these cases.

Comment: @Anwar They all use Windows OS, they only provided me with credentials

Comment: You need to know which type of VPN clients you find an accurate answer. Or which equivalent windows software they use?

Comment: @Anwar We use PPTP VPN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connecting to PPTP VPN in Kubuntu 16.04 is easy. Follow the procedure:

1. Click on the Network Manager Icon on the Panel

   [image: Network Icon]

   If you can't find that icon, install `plasma-nm` package.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install plasma-nm
   ```

   and add the widget to the panel
2. In the Opened Pop-Up notification, click on the Settings Icon at the right side.

   [image: Settings Icon]
3. On the New **Connection Editor** window, Click on the **Add button** and select **Point-to-Point Tunneling Protocol** from the dropdown menu.

   [image: pptp]
4. On the **New Connection (vpn)** window, provide the vpn address in the *Gateway* field, fill username and password and click OK to save. You can leave NT Domain field empty.

Now you can connect to the VPN from the Network Manager Widget.

From OPs feedback, it seems you need to click on **Advanced** tab in Create new connection window and enable the option for **USE MPPE Encryption** option to be enable to use with Windows VPN.

Check the screenshot below for that

[image: special settings for windows vpn]

Comment: I get connection stopped error. On Win10 same credentials work.

Comment: @Kunok did you follow the exact procedure?

Comment: Ok, I just want to add that if you are connecting to windows VPN then you need to configure some settings first in Advanaced. See screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/39uWX80.png   and then connection works.

Comment: @Kunok thank you for the feedback. I've included that information in the answer